# How to Set Uninstall (InstallLocation) Registry Key Value in WIX Installer

Tags: wix, installation

I am writing a utility for our lab that checks the installed software on the local machine against a collection of installers (msi files) on a NAS.  From a bit of web searching, it seemed like the preferred approach for determining what packages are installed on a Windows based machine from within code is to iterate over the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` keys.  The installers that I am interested in are namespaced ( and created by me) so picking the registry keys that I am interested in is easy, but I have noticed the installers that I have created using wix are not setting the InstallLocation key like most of the other installers are doing.

[image]

Since I am not specifically setting any of these keys (within the Uninstall\XYZ section) within the wix installer specifically, I am assuming there are some installer attributes that are being used to populate the existing keys.  Does anyone know the proper way to have the InstallLocation filled out by the wix installer?  I am currently using WIX 3.8 at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a place to look if you are creating the MSI files:

http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2011/1/14/arpinstalllocation-and-how-to-set-it-with-the-wix-toolset/

If they belong to other companies there's not much you can so.

Comment: I had seen that article and tried to add the set property as discussed, and did not get the InstallLocation registry key set.  Figured I misunderstood the intent of the article since it never really mentions this specific registry key in the text.  I did find another reference to this after seeing your post, so perhaps I am using it incorrectly.  I will try a few things and report back.

Comment: Looks like I was using the wrong Value for my set call.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Can you please describe what you did for this as I'm trying to do the same thing and I am a WIX newbie!

Comment: The WiX source is at that link, it's very explicit, it's hard to know what else to say about it.

Comment: The text between the brackets needs to be the ID of the Directory element you're targeting. Many examples use `INSTALLFOLDER`.